# android widget doesn't update

Tags: android, widget

i am developing a digital widget for android and i am stuck at updating my widget

i set an on update override and used Bitmaps to show hour and minute with typeface but when i add that to my phone's home screen it doesn't update i mean the it doesn't show updated time

here is my widget class:
first i have the on update Override:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {

        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());

        today.setToNow();

        int hour = today.hour;

        CharSequence h = Integer.toString(hour);

        String hh = h.toString();

        int minute = today.minute;

        CharSequence m = Integer.toString(minute);

        String mm = ":" + m.toString();

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView1, getFontBitmap(context, hh, Color.WHITE, 70));

        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView2, getFontBitmap1(context, mm, Color.WHITE, 70));

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

and then Bitmaps

```
public static Bitmap getFontBitmap(Context context, String text, int color, float fontSizeSP) {
    int fontSizePX = convertDiptoPix(context, fontSizeSP);
    int pad = (fontSizePX / 9);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "bold.ttf");
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTypeface(typeface);
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setTextSize(fontSizePX);

    int textWidth = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + pad * 2);
    int height = (int) (fontSizePX / 0.75);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textWidth, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    float xOriginal = pad;
    canvas.drawText(text, xOriginal, fontSizePX, paint);
    return bitmap;
}
public static Bitmap getFontBitmap1(Context context, String text, int color, float fontSizeSP) {
    int fontSizePX = convertDiptoPix(context, fontSizeSP);
    int pad = (fontSizePX / 9);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "thin.ttf");
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTypeface(typeface);
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setTextSize(fontSizePX);

    int textWidth = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + pad * 2);
    int height = (int) (fontSizePX / 0.75);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textWidth, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    float xOriginal = pad;
    canvas.drawText(text, xOriginal, fontSizePX, paint);
    return bitmap;
}
public static int convertDiptoPix(Context context, float dip) {
    int value = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dip, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    return value;
}
```

and here is my widget.xml in res/xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:minWidth="288dp" 
    android:minHeight="144dp" 
    android:updatePeriodMillis="10000" 
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout">
</appwidget-provider>
```

and this is my receiver

```
           <receiver android:name="widget">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
       </intent-filter>
       <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
           android:resource="@xml/widget"/>
   </receiver>
```

so any help?