# getting updateable time in android

Tags: android, time

How can I get time in android that changes automatically when phone's time change
I use this code but it doesn't update (I use that in a widget)

```
Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
today.setToNow();
int hour = today.hour;
String hh = Integer.toString(hour);

int minute = today.minute;
String mm = ":" + Integer.toString(minute);
```

and here is my widget codes

[android widget doesn't update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500355/android-widget-doesnt-update)

Comment: I think you will have to roll your own solution to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Calendar.getInstance` to get the current date and time from the system.

Answer (score 0):

To update time every second

```
final  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
     int hh = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
     int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
     String mm = hh+":"+mm; // updated time 
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer("mytimer");    
timer.schedule(task ,1000, 1000); //
```